# Conditionally clear contents of range of cells in a row based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with two sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet 1 has store information while Sheet 2 has product quantity by store information

In Sheet 1, Range "A1:A5" lists 5 store names, Store A through Store E, while range "B1:B5" in Sheet 1 is a drop down box that lets the user choose from the following: "Open", "Closed", or "".

In Sheet 2, there is a table that lists the quantity of products by store. Something like:

[image]

I am looking for a way to clear the contents of range B:F in Sheet2 when the respective store in Sheet1 is not set to "Open".

Currently, I am linking the values in Column B from Sheet1 to Column G in Sheet2, and have set the code to the following in Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
If Range("G2") <> "Open" Then
Range("B2:F2").ClearContents
End If
```

How can I perform this in a loop rather than copying this code five separate times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
For i = 2 To 6 'This is the starting row (2) to the ending row (6)
    If Range("G" & i) <> "Open" Then 'We use i to dynamically build the range as a string
        Range("B" & i & ":F" & i).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it should work. I saw something similar to this on another answer but did not have comments and therefore did not fully understand what the code was doing. I'll try this and provide and update shortly. Thank you!

Comment: Also, is there any way the If statement can refer to Column B on Sheet1 rather than Column G on Sheet2? In otherwords, something like Sheet1.Range("A" & i)?

Comment: Change your reference like this: `Range("Sheet2!G" & i)`